# Dynamic random call to image elements to XAML from C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following code in C#. A function by which I want to highlight one of the nine images at random. The code is as follows,

```
    public void randomize(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        String img = "image";
        int random = RandomNumber(10, 18);    //Generate Random Number
        score.Content = random;             
        img += random;                      //append generated number to "image"

        //Call function to highlight behind image
        ToGold(random);
    }
```

I tried to make the function call `ToGold(random)` to be able to dynamically refer to one of the images on XAML. But I was not able to make the code work as I intended. So I took a brute force approach as below,

```
    public void ToGold(int Img)
    {
        Uri gold = new Uri("/Start;component/Images/gold1.png", UriKind.Relative);     //Set Uri path of gold image
        ImageSource ImgSrc = new BitmapImage(gold);                                    //Define ImageSource and assign

        switch(Img)
        {
            case 10:
                {
                    image10.Source = ImgSrc;
                    break;
                }
            case 11:
                {
                    image11.Source = ImgSrc;
                    break;
                }
            case 12:
                {
                    image12.Source = ImgSrc;
                    break;
                }
            case 13:
                {
                    image13.Source = ImgSrc;
                    break;
                }
            case 14:
                {
                    image14.Source = ImgSrc;
                    break;
                }
            case 15:
                {
                    image15.Source = ImgSrc;
                    break;
                }
            case 16:
                {
                    image16.Source = ImgSrc;
                    break;
                }
            case 17:
                {
                    image17.Source = ImgSrc;
                    break;
                }
            case 18:
                {
                    image18.Source = ImgSrc;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
```

So my question is how do I make the code efficient by making it dynamic? Can anyone please help me?

NOTE: I have just started studying WPF. So please bear with me.

Comment: It is highly recommendable that you use an `ItemsControl` instead of manually manipulating UI elements  in procedural code like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx) method on the window to find an element by its name.
Or you could create an array containing your images in order, i.e. `{ image0, image1, image2, image3, ... }` and then access that array with a random index.